# Generating forms automatically based on data model

Tags: php, zend-framework, codeigniter, cakephp, symfony1

Some time ago I was reading about symfony and it's ability to generate forms automatically based on the data model. For instance if a table has a foreign key from another table, then the form will contain a dropdown list with the available values from that foreign key.

**What are the other PHP frameworks which support this functionality?**

Comment: Any kind of data model or only for mysql?

Comment: ideally mysql. I would like to be able to create my model using something like mysql workbench then generate automatically my forms.

Comment: So then use symfony, or what's the problem?

Comment: Based on Google trends and other indicators it doesn't seem widely used, and I would like to choose a tool which has growth potential and good documentation:
http://www.google.com/trends?q=cakephp%2C+codeigniter%2C+zend%2C+symfony&ctab=0&geo=all&date=2011&sort=0

Comment: Well, then let google suggest you one if you take these trends as a measurement bar.

Comment: I would suggest that the reason Symfony is so low on the Google Search Trends list is because the single most useful place for Symfony is the official page - it really is the only Bookmark you need - the documentation is excellent - I have personally used Symfony a lot in production and never had any major problems with it. Highly recommend you investigate further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [zfdatagrid.com](http://zfdatagrid.com)
I didn't use it but it looks like can have elements you need and may try to extract them.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand - all frameworks should be able to get you any associated content depending on how you setup your database relationships and model relationships (hasMany, belongsTo etc). As far as form generation goes - they all also have some form of "CRUD" scaffolding where a command would generate forms for you. Best is to read up on their documentations and see which is more suited to your task.

Answer (score 0):

You also can try to use [symfony's](http://www.symfony-project.org/) one. You can generate the forms for the entire database model with just one command:

```
php symfony propel:build-forms
```

The bad issue is that you need to do some work (really few ;)) configuring the ORM, and if you need only to generate the forms, may symfony be too large for you.

Good luck